# Showing $k[X] \cong k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. I want to show that $(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$ is a prime ideal of $k[X,Y,Z]$.

I know that an ideal $\frak a \subseteq$ $R$ of a (commutative ring with $1$) is prime if any only if $R\big/{\frak a}$ is an integral domain.

Thus I understand that if we can show that $k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)}$ is an integral domain, we're done.

Now this exercise's solution I am trying to understand is stating that the homomorphism \begin{align*} k[X]&\to k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)}\\ X&\mapsto X\end{align*}

has an inverse via

\begin{align*} k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)} &\to k[X] \\ X&\mapsto X \\ Y&\mapsto X^2 \\ Z&\mapsto X^3\end{align*}

and thus they claim $k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)}$ to be an integral domain.

---

I don't fully understand the proposed solution and have some questions.

**Question 1:** How to come up with these maps in the first place?

I am aware of the natural inclusion $k[X]\subset k[X,Y,Z]$, so the first map is kind of an obvious choice, maybe. But how to come up with the inverse map? What role does the quotient ring play in terms of "finding the inverse map" or rather "seeing the obvious choice"?

In other words: Why are these maps "obvious"?

**Question 2:** I suppose the key observation in having this inverse map is that this shows that $$k[X] \cong k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)}$$ and since $k[X]$ is an integral domain, the quotient ring $k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)}$ is an integral domain, too. Is that correct?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: +1 and apologies for ruining your 1729 rep :(

Comment: thank you vm :) is 1729 some special integer i'm not aware of?

Comment: It features in [a nice mathematical anecdote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number).

Comment: Ah, nice, i've actually heard of it but apparently didnt remember it to be 1729. Thanks for the clarification:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $Y-X^2$ and $Z-X^3$ are quotiented out means that in the quotient you have $Y=X^2$ and $Z=X^3$. Thus it makes sense to see if the map
$$\begin{align*} k[X,Y,Z]\big/{(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)} &\to k[X] \\ X&\mapsto X \\ Y&\mapsto X^2 \\ Z&\mapsto X^3\end{align*},$$
is an isomorphism, or at least injective, as then it follows that the quotient is an integral domain.

Comment: hello @Servaes, thanks for your answer, would you mind elaborating a bit? I still have some issues fully understanding what were doing. Why is it sufficient to just describe the map on $X,Y,Z$ and why does injectivity imply isomorphism?

Comment: Injectivity doesn't imply isomorphism. It shows that the quotient is (isomorphic to) a subring of an integral domain, and hence it is itself an integral domain.

Comment: Ah, i see, that makes sense, thanks a lot. I guess i'm still having a hard time understand why we choose to define the map in terms of $X,Y,Z$, i am mostly used of defining maps on generating elements, but these particular $X,Y,Z$ do not play the role of generators, do they? I'm still a bit confused on how to understand why this map has been chosen.

Comment: And as you state, we want to show that the quotient is an integral domain. Instead of trying to do some awful algebraic manipulations in the quotient to show that there are no zero divisors, with no guarantee of success, it makes sense to first find a simpler representation of the quotient by eliminating some variables. In this particular quotient the variables $Y$ and $Z$ are easily eliminated; it turns out that every element of the quotient has a representative in $k[X]$.

Comment: And in fact $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ *do* define the map entirely, if we assume that the map is $k$-linear. Then we simply get the map $$k[X,Y,Z] \longrightarrow\ k[X]:\ p(X,Y,Z)\ \longmapsto\ p(X,X^2,X^3).$$ This $k$-linearity is often implicitly assumed in the context of polynomial rings.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments @Servaes. So can i take it that maps between polynomial rings can indeed be considered to be $k$-linear, s.t. for $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ the $X_i$ might be handled as if they were generators?

Comment: Yes. To throw in some jargon; the $X_i$ generate $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ as a $k$-algebra, and so it suffices to define a map of $k$-algebras on just the $X_i$. Have a look at [associative algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra) if you like.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you very much. I couldn't find any information whether the $X_i$ actually generate $k[X_1,...,X_n]$. I guess this simplies things a lot. I really appreciate your patience with me, thank you so much!